# Different ways to authenticate to a REST Webservice

Tags: web-services, rest, authentication, oauth, hmac

I need to sum up different ways to authenticate to a REST Webservice. Of course there is the Basic Authentication and i also found the Digest access authentication and the authentication with HMAC.

In [RFC2617](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2617) there is the Digest access authentication specified as a method, which hash

> the username, the password, the given
> nonce value, the HTTP method, and the requested URI

and then send this hash with the parameter (but not the password) to the server to authenticate.

Now the Question: Is there a difference / What is the difference between the digest authentication and HMAC?

Using HMAC for authentication, i also have to concat some Strings and hash them...

What are other methodes of autentication? I tried to understand OAuth ([RFC6749](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#page-7)) but for me it seems to be a Framework which based on other methodes:

> Clients in possession of a client password MAY use the HTTP Basic
> authentication scheme as defined in [RFC2617] to authenticate with
> the authorization server